# mypyc: Implementing a proxy object

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, mypyc

Is there a way to implement a proxy object with mypyc?

For example, consider the following code which works fine with Python but not mypyc:

```py
import typing


class Thing:
    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> typing.Any:
        return 5

t = Thing()
print(t.lol)
```

Python output:

```
5
```

mypyc compiled output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "blah.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(t.lol)
AttributeError: 'Thing' object has no attribute 'lol'
```

Comment: `mypyc` supports a subset of Python.  This is not in the subset, I guess.

Comment: Seems that way. Would be nice if there was some way to figure this out though... I need a proxy :-(

Comment: These are limits of mypyc native class: https://mypyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/native_classes.html#native-classes

Comment: I just went ahead and added support in a fork of mypy. Hopefully they will pick it up: https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/10211